# How can i fix to make Axios post working in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a code to do login task:

```
                onSubmit() {
                    this.$q.loading.show();
                    this.$axios.post("http://localhost/adminision/api/usermanager/login.php", 
                    {
                        language: "vi",
                        instituteid: this.$store.state.mainState.istituto,
                        username: this.username,
                        password: this.passwd
                    }).then((t => {
                        1 == t.data.success ? (this.$store.commit("mainState/setLoginData", t.data.token), this.$store.commit("mainState/setFirstName", t.data.firstName), this.$store.commit("mainState/setLastName", t.data.lastName), this.$store.commit("mainState/setMatrixID", "login"), this.$q.sessionStorage.set("token", t.data.token), this.$router.push({
                            path: "/dashboard"
                        })) : (this.$q.loading.hide(), this.validatormessage = "Username or password not valid", this.mostraerrori = !0)
                    })).catch((t => {
                        this.validatormessage = t.response.data.error.description, this.mostraerrori = !0
                    }))
                },
```

But when i click submit button, this.$axios.post runs, but nothing happens. No login.php appear in Network tab of Chrome browser, with no js error. I've set breakpoint in catch body but it is unreachable.
So, please help, what can i do ?

Answer (score -1):

You have syntax error in your code. Each line should have been ended with `semicolon` instead of `comma` or If you leave it javascript ASI will auto insert it:

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.$q.loading.show();
  this.$axios.post("http://localhost/adminision/api/usermanager/login.php", {
    language: "vi",
    instituteid: this.$store.state.mainState.istituto,
    username: this.username,
    password: this.passwd
  }).then((t => {
    if (t.data.susccess === 1) {
      this.$store.commit("mainState/setLoginData", t.data.token);
      this.$store.commit("mainState/setFirstName", t.data.firstName);
      this.$store.commit("mainState/setLastName", t.data.lastName);
      this.$store.commit("mainState/setMatrixID", "login");
      this.$q.sessionStorage.set("token", t.data.token);
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/dashboard"
      })
    } else {
      this.$q.loading.hide();
      this.validatormessage = "Username or password not valid";
      this.mostraerrori = !0;
    }
  })).catch((t) => {
    this.validatormessage = t.response.data.error.description;
    this.mostraerrori = !0;
  })
},
```

Comment: Still not working. Problem is no js error. No post. Nothing happens.